# C# ASP.NET Date and Time without jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am new to ASP.NET and want to use date and time for the user to enter their desired date. I have looked around and saw people using jQuery but is there another way to implement it nicely?

Comment: "Other way" as in ASP.NET only?

Comment: Of course there's another way; you could roll your own. Without more specifics, no one's going to be able to give you what you're looking for. "Nicely" is super vague and highly subjective.

Comment: Is there any issue with javascript? I mean it's the best way to create and maintain it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can add the Calendar control to get the information you need. If that's a bit heavy for what you're wanting, you can also just create input's for the various fields (make sure you add all of the error checking to make sure it's a valid date/time entry).

To answer the "implement it nicely" part of your question. I personally don't like using the built in Calendar control because it's clunky and a bit ugly. With the jQuery (or other 3rd party controls) you get the functionality plus easy to use formatting. Unless you're in a position where jQuery is not allowed, I'd use it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for UI to show DateTime picker. I am currently using Kendo UI. You may want to take a look at this nice UI framework. But I am not sure if they offer this one for free or not.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index